# Git branch not showing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

In Git I can see my Master branch and a feature branch named Shadow. I imported the project to Eclipse via Git URI import and I have pushed changes to Master. Now I wanted to do a 'Switch to > Shadow' but Shadow branch is not showing in Eclipse for me. Screenshots attached.[image: Git]

[image: SwitchTo][image: fetch from upstream]

Comment: The menu only contains branches you had checked out locally. Select "Other..." and then select the remote branch. The select "Check out" and "Check out as new local branch".

Comment: I can see only master in remote. Are you asking me to check out as new branch from branch and name it shadow?

Answer (score 0):

Try checkout outside of Eclipse: git checkout shadow .
After that it should be available to change the branch graphically.